# All your bijective base are belong to us

Tags: code-golf, math, base-conversion

#### Background

A [bijective base **b** numeration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration), where **b** is a positive integer, is a bijective positional notation that makes use of **b** symbols with associated values of **1** to **b**.

Unlike its non-bijective counterpart, no symbol has a value of **0**. This way, each non-negative integer **n** has a *unique* representation in bijective base **b**.

Popular bijective numerations include unary, bijective base 2 (used in [bzip2's run-length encoding](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/53062)) and bijective base 26 (used to number columns in spreadsheets).

#### Definition

In this challenge, we define the set **M** of symbols as

```
123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz<=>
```

and a function **i** from **M** to the natural number such that **i('1') = 1, …, i('>') = 64**.

Given a base **b** between **1** and **64** (both inclusive), we define that each non-negative integer **n** corresponds to the string **a<sub>k</sub>…a<sub>0</sub>**, consisting  of symbols of **M**, such that **n = b<sup>k</sup>i(a<sub>k</sub>)+…+b<sup>0</sup>i(a<sub>0</sub>)**.

This correspondence is well-defined and bijective. Since an empty sum is defined as **0**, the integer **0** can be encoded as an empty string.

#### Task

Accept three strings as input:

- An input base **b** between **1** and **64**, encoded as a bijective base **64** string.
- A non-negative integer **n**, encoded as a bijective base **b** string.
- An output base **B** between **1** and **64**, encoded as a bijective base **64** string.

Given these three inputs, encode **n** as a bijective base **B** string.

#### Test cases

All test cases specify the input in the order **b**, **n**, **B**.

```
Input:  "4" "" "8"
Output: ""

Input:  "A" "16" "2"
Output: "1112"

Input:  "2" "122" "A"
Output: "A"

Input:  "3" "31" "1"
Output: "1111111111"

Input:  ">" "Fe" "a"
Output: "RS"
```

#### Rules

- You may read the three strings in any convenient order, as such, an array of strings, a string representation thereof, concatenated or separated by single-character delimiters of your choice.
- If you choose to print the output to STDOUT, you may only print the symbols and (optionally) a trailing newline.
- Base conversion built-ins of all kinds are allowed.
- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## CJam, 43

```
qA,s"?[a{A<":,:^+:Mf#):B;(bLa{(Bmd)M=\j\+}j
```

3 bytes eradicated with [help](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54348/7416) from Dennis :) [Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qA%2Cs%22%3F%5Ba%7BA%3C%22%3A%2C%3A%5E%2B%3AMf%23)%3AB%3B(bLa%7B(Bmd)M%3D%5Cj%5C%2B%7Dj&input=%3EFea)

**Explanation:**

The input is taken as `bnB`, concatenated into a single string.

```
q           read the input
A,s         make an array of numbers from 0 to 9 and convert to string
"?[a{A<"    push this string, which contains the ends of 3 character ranges:
             uppercase letters: ['A'…'[')
             lowercase letters: ['a'…'{')
             "<=>": ['<'…'?')
             they're in a special order for the symmetric difference below
:,          for each character, make a range of all characters smaller than it
:^          fold/reduce these 6 ranges using symmetric difference
+           concatenate with the digits before
:M          save in M; this is like the M from the statement,
             except it starts with a zero (for matching indexes)
f#          find the indexes in M of all characters from the input string
)           take out the last value from the array
:B;         save it in B and pop it
(           take out the first value
b           use it as a base and convert the remaining array to a number
             this works even if some of the digits are not in the "normal" range
La{…}j      calculate with memoized recursion, using an empty string for value 0
  (         decrement the number
  Bmd       divide by B and get the quotient and remainder
  )         increment the remainder (this is the last digit in bijective base B)
  M=        get the corresponding character from M
  \j        swap with the quotient, and convert the quotient recursively
  \+        swap again and concatenate
```

Comment: Oh, you can actually use the regular base conversion operator for the first base conversion? Now I feel silly for using all the code I have in my solution. :) I didn't realize that it would work with values that are outside the range of the base. Well, in hindsight, there's no good reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes, you can do that; one day it will be documented :)

Comment: Do you mind if I change my solution to use the base conversion? I normally try to avoid taking ideas from other solutions. But it really bugs me to let mine stand with such a sub-optimal approach. It's highly likely that your solution will still be shorter.

Comment: @RetoKoradi no problem, go ahead

Answer (score 5):

## Pip, <s>84</s> <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```
m:J[,tAZLCAZ"<=>"]p:$+(m@?^b)*(m@?a)**RV,#bs:m@?cWn:px:(mn-(p:n//s-!n%s)*s).xx
```

[GitHub repository for Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip)

Algorithms adapted from the Wikipedia article. Here's the explanation for a slightly ungolfed earlier version:

```
                 Implicit: initialize a,b,c from cmdline args; t=10;
                 AZ=uppercase alphabet; x=""
m:               Build lookup table m:
 (J,t)             0123456789 (i.e. join(range(10)))...
 .AZ               plus A-Z...
 .LCAZ             plus lowercase a-z...
 ."<=>"            plus <=>
f:{              Define f(a,b) to convert a from bijective base b to decimal:
 $+                Sum of...
  (m@?^a)            list of index of each character of a in m
  *                  multiplied item-wise by 
  b**RV,#a           b to the power of each number in reverse(range(len(a)))
}
t:{              Define t(a,b) to convert a from decimal to bijective base b:
 x:""              Reset x to empty string (not needed if only calling the function once)
 Wa{               While a is not zero:
  p:a//b-!a%b        p = ceil(a/b) - 1 (= a//b if a%b!=0, a//b-1 otherwise)
  x:m@(a-p*b).x      Calculate digit a-p*b, look up the corresponding character in m, and
                     prepend to x
  a:p                p becomes the new a
 }
 x                 Return x
}
(t               Return result of calling t with these arguments:
 (f                Result of calling f with these arguments:
  b                  2nd cmdline arg
  m@?a)              1st cmdline arg's decimal value
 m@?c              3rd cmdline arg's decimal value
)
                 Print (implicit)
```

Sample run:

```
dlosc@dlosc:~/golf$ python pip.py bijectivebase.pip ">" "Fe" "a"
RS
```

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 166 bytes

```
function z=b(o,x,n)
M=['1':'9','A':'Z','a':'z','<=>'];N(M)=1:64;n=N(n);x=polyval(N(x),N(o));z='';while x>0 r=mod(x,n);t=n;if r t=r;end;z=[M(t),z];x=fix(x/n)-(r<1);end
```

Multi-line version:

```
function z=b(o,x,n)
   M=['1':'9','A':'Z','a':'z','<=>'];
   N(M)=1:64;
   n=N(n);
   x=polyval(N(x),N(o));
   z='';
   while x>0
      r=mod(x,n);
      t=n;if r t=r;end;
      z=[M(t),z];
      x=fix(x/n)-(r<1);
   end
%end // implicit - not included above
```

Rather than create a map to convert a character to an index value, I just created the inverse lookup table `N` for ascii values `1..'z'` and populated it with the indices at the appropriate values.

`polyval` evaluates the equation

> c<sub>1</sub>x<sup>k</sup> + c<sub>2</sub>x<sup>k-1</sup> + ... + c<sub>k</sub>x<sup>0</sup>

using the decimal-converted input value as the vector of coefficients `c` and the original base as `x`. (Unfortunately, Octave's `base2dec()` rejects symbols out of the normal range.)

Once we have the input value in base 10, calculation of the value in the new base is straightforward.

Test driver:

```
% script bijecttest.m
a=b('4','','8');
disp(a);
a=b('A','16','2');
disp(a);
a=b('2','122','A');
disp(a);
a=b('3','31','1');
disp(a);
a=b('>','Fe','a');
disp(a);
```

Results:

```
>> bijecttest

1112
A
1111111111
RS
>>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, <s>261</s> <s>248</s> 229 bytes

```
sub t{$b=0;$b*=$_[1],$b+=ord($1=~y/0-9A-Za-z<=>/\0-A/r)while$_[0]=~/(.)/g;return$b}sub r{$n=$_[0];$n-=$m=($n-1)%$_[1]+1,$d=(chr$m)=~y/\0-A/0-9A-Za-z<=>/r.$d,$n/=$_[1]while$n;print$d}@a=split/,/,<>;r(t(@a[1],t@a[0],64),t@a[2],64)
```

multi-line, while loops ungolfed:

```
sub t{ # convert bijective base string to number
    $b=0;
    while($_[0]=~/(.)/g)
        {$b*=$_[1];$b+=ord($1=~y/0-9A-Za-z<=>/\0-A/r)}
    return$b}
sub r{ # convert number to bijective base string
    $n=$_[0];
    while($n)
        {$n-=$m=($n-1)%$_[1]+1;$d=(chr$m)=~y/\0-A/0-9A-Za-z<=>/r.$d;$n/=$_[1]}
    print$d}
@a=split/,/,<>; # parse input
r(t(@a[1],t@a[0],64),t@a[2],64)
```

`t` is a function to parse a number from a bijective-base string of a given base. `r` is a function to generate a bijective-base string of a given base from a number. The 3 comma-separated parameters are parsed from stdin and the functions are called as needed.

Converting a positive number to a bijective base string is similar to a normal base. However where you would do something like this for a normal base:

```
string s = ""
while(n)
{
    c = (n % base)
    s = (c + '0') + s
    n -= c // not necessary because the division will take care of it
    n /= base 
}
```

you adjust the mod to give a range from 1 to base instead of 0 to base - 1:

```
string s = ""
while(n)
{
    c = (((n-1) % base)+1)
    s = (c + '0') + s
    n -= c  // necessary in the case c = base
    n /= base 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>73</s> <s>70</s> <s>69</s> <s>55</s> <s>51</s> 48 bytes

Latest version uses the CJam base conversion operator for the conversion from the source base, which I hadn't thought of until I saw @aditsu's solution. It also applies a recent tip by @Dennis for constructing the "digit" string (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/54348/32852), as well as some other ideas shared on chat.

```
lA,s'[,_el^+"<=>"+:Lf#Ll#bLl#:K;{(Kmd)L=\}hs-]W%
```

Input format is the value, followed by the source and destination base, with each of them on a separate line. For the empty string, leave the first line empty. Example input:

```
122
2
A
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=lA%2Cs'%5B%2C_el%5E%2B%22%3C%3D%3E%22%2B%3ALf%23Ll%23bLl%23%3AK%3B%7B(Kmd)L%3D%5C%7Dhs-%5DW%25&input=Fe%0A%3E%0Aa)

Explanation:

```
l       Get and interpret value from input.
A,s     Build the list of 64 "digits". Start with [0..9]
'[,     Build character sequence from \0 to Z.
_el     Lower case copy of the same sequence.
^       Symmetric set difference gives only letters from both sequences.
+       Concatenate with sequence of decimal digits, creating [0..9A..Za..z].
"<=>"   Remaining 4 characters.
+       Concatenate, resulting in full 64 character "digit" string.
:L      ... and store it in variable L for repeated use.
f#      Look up input characters in digit list.
Ll#     Get source base from input, and look up value in digit list.
b       Base conversion. This produces the input value.
Ll#     Get destination base from input, and look up value in digit list.
:K;     Store it in variable K for use in loop, and pop it off stack.
{       Loop for generating output digits.
  (       Decrement to get ceiling minus 1 after division.
  Kmd     Calculate divmod of current value with destination base.
  )       Increment mod to get 1-based value for digit.
  L=      Look up digit character for digit value.
  \       Swap. Digit stays on stack for output, remaining value is processed
          in next loop iteration until it is 0.
}h      End of loop for generating output digits.
s       Final value is 0. Covert it to a string.
-       And subtract it from second but last value. This eliminates the 0,
        as well as the second but last value if it was a \0 character.
]       Wrap digits in array.
W%      Reverse array, to get result from MSB to LSB.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, ... <s>317</s> <s>307</s> <s>298</s> 311 bytes

Definitely golfable. I really hate how strings have no item assignment and lists have no `find`. I'll look into a better way than my fast fix that I have now.

My method is to convert the input to a decimal number, then to the output base, then convert that to the bijective base.

**Edit**: Found that my program didn't work when converting to Unary. It cost 13 bytes to fix with `e=F(o)<2`, etc.

[**Try it here**](http://ideone.com/hgbqj0)

```python
R=range;M="".join(map(chr,R(48,58)+R(65,91)+R(97,123)))+"<=>"
b,s,o=input()
F=M.find
e=F(o)<2
B=lambda n:n and B(n/F(o)-e)+M[n%F(o)+e]or""
n=B(sum(F(s[~j])*F(b)**j for j in R(len(s))))
i=n.find('0')
n=list(n)
while-~i:n=n[:i-1]+[M[F(n[i-1])-1]]+[o]+n[i+1:];n=n["0"==n[0]:];i="".join(n).find('0')
print"".join(n)
```

Comment: I agree with your Python pet peeves.

Comment: @DLosc Thanks for the golf help.

Comment: is this [tag:code-bowling] ? :P

Comment: Lists have the `.index()` method.. Why not use that instead of find? Also, instead of saving `F(b)` and `F(o)` to variables, you only use them once, so just sub them in where necessary. Finally, `'n'[2::5]` is shorter than `''.join(n)` (replace apostrophes for backticks).

Comment: Also, I think you're over-complicating this.. Conversion from a string M bijective base b to decimal shouldn't take more than 35-40 bytes. Decimal to a string of bijective base B won't be much more than that.

Comment: I can't use backticks around `n`, since n can be a long. I cannot use `.index()` on the list, since the list isn't guaranteed to contain `'0'`, and would throw an exception in such a case.

Comment: @Vioz- I'd have to use `str(n)[2::5]` or `\`n\`[2:-1:5]`, both of which are longer.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 167 Bytes

No special tricks in here really, except for the `[2::5]` slicing to get the charset at a lower byte count.

```py
x=range;A=`map(chr,x(49,58)+x(65,91)+x(97,123))`[2::5]+'<=>'
r=A.find
b,n,B=input()
B=r(B)+1
d=0;s=''
for c in n:d=d*-~r(b)+r(c)+1
while d:d-=1;s=A[d%B]+s;d/=B
print s
```

Tests:

```py
"4","","8"     >>> (empty string)
">","Fe","a"   >>> RS
"3","31","1"   >>> 1111111111
"A","16","2"   >>> 1112
"2","122","A"  >>> A
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 bytes

```
ØBḊ;“<=>”
i@€€¢ḅḃ2ƭ/ị¢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDKeHO7qsHzXMsbG1e9QwlyvT4VHTGiA6tOjhjtaHO5qNjq3Vf7i7@9Ci////R6u7parrKKjbgYhE9VgA)