# Can you find the villain's password?

Tags: code-golf

#### Background

You work for the police force as a programmer.

A villain has planted a bomb in the city, luckily the police force has captured both him and the bomb. The bomb is really complicated to disarm, however it has a password input to disarm it.

The villain, being cocky, has told you that there was no way you'd find the password as you'd take X time to brute force it. You notice that the keyboard can only input english letters (lower and upper case) and digits.

#### Task

Assuming you can try Y passwords per second, and that the brute force character order would be `a-z A-Z 0-9`, you are to create either a full program or a function that takes as input both X (in seconds) and Y (passwords/second) and outputs the villain's password.

X can be a float but Y will always be an integer.
**(X*Y should always be an integer)**

Your code has to solve the problem using math instead of relying on trying several options or creating huge arrays and simply indexing them with X*Y.

#### Example in JS

```
var c="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
var b=62;
function num(x){
    var n=0;
    while(x>=0){
        x-=Math.pow(b,++n);
    }
    return n;
}
function reduce(x, n){
    while(--n>0){
        x-=Math.pow(b,n);
    }
    return x;
}
function pass(x, y){
    x=x*y;
    x--;
    var p=[];
    var n=num(x);
    x = reduce(x, n);
    do{
        var t=x%b;
        x=(x-t)/b;
        p.unshift(t);
    }while(x>0);
    return ("a".repeat(n)+p.map(f=>c[f]).join``).substr(-n);
}
```

Assuming my code is correct here are some example outputs.
**(If there are any errors please tell me so that I can correct them)**

```
pass(0.000, 1000); // "" or anything that won't be mistaken for a password
pass(0.001, 1000); // "a"
pass(0.002, 1000); // "b"
pass(0.027, 1000); // "A"

//A password that would take a year to brute force at 1000 passwords/second
pass(3600*24*365, 1000) // "HzmZmr"
```

My code is awful and ungolfed but it's only to serve as an example. Since this is code-golf shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: "You cannot brute force" I'm not quite sure what that implies... does it mean we can't simply generate the next Y passwords each second and then output after X seconds?

Comment: Also, will X always be an integer, or can it be floating-point?

Comment: @ETHproductions Yes. You shouldn't just generate several passwords and choose one or anything similar. You should instead get there through math and logic. Also both X and Y should be integers. I'll specify that in the question.

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're expecting here... You haven't provided information about how we could guess the password without a brute force approach. Is there a valid timing attack against the bomb? Is the password hashed in the bomb's database/memory? Maybe it's a weak hashing algorithm? What logical path are you expecting us to follow?

Comment: Oh I think I get it... we know that X is the upper bound on time so we take the Y passwords/second and generate Z passwords where Z = XY? Then the Z'th password would be correct? If this is the case, what's the minimum length password that the bomb accepts?

Comment: @Poke I think we are supposed to output the (X*Y)th string from `a, b, c,..., y, z, A, B,...,Y, Z, 0, 1, ..., 8, 9, aa, ab, ac, ad,...`. I'm voting to close as unclear until that gets cleared up though.

Comment: @Riley Yea, but explaining it like that will just make people brute force passwords with a counter. And I was thinking about using math to get there.

Comment: I think the updates to the question are good but it's generally discouraged to ask [Do X without Y](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8079#8079) questions. In this case I see what you're going for and some people may be able to golf it really nicely but brute force is a much simpler algorithm.

Comment: Maybe you could add restricted-complexity as tag, and require that the algorithm is better than linear in respect to X\*Y. 
Incidentally, could we assume that X\*Y is always an integer?

Comment: @Leo I feel like that could possibly restrict more solutions, and X*Y will always be integer.

Comment: It's not totally clear what you mean by "brute-force" here

Comment: @LuisMendo Your code shouldn't loop over every password with a counter or generate huge arrays and index them with X*Y. Instead your code should get there directly with some math, like in my example.

Comment: Before posting your challenges, you could post on [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) first, there you can receive some feedback to improve your challenge.

Comment: This still needs an actual specification (making us reverse engineer it from a reference implementation doesn't count), but judging by the answers it would likely be close enough to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/54105/194 to be closed as a dupe anyway.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
×ḃ62ịØWŒs
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@394@sMdzWZGD3d3H54RfnRS8f///40NTY3NDAwM/hsCCQA)**

#### How?

```
×ḃ62ịØWŒs - Main link: X, Y
×         - multiply X by Y
 ḃ62      - convert to bijective base 62 (uses modulo arithmetic under the hood)
    ị     - index into (1-based)
     ØW   - word yield -> "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_"
       Œs - swap case
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 121 bytes

```python
x,y=input()
r=range;b=map(chr,r(97,123)+r(65,91)+r(48,58))
i=int(x*y)
p=b[i%62]
while i/62>0:i=i/62-1;p=b[i%62]+p
print p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#PYzBCoMwEAXv@YpcCklM6SbRVCvpj4gHLVIDVpbFUv36NL30NjBvXtr1EeKK701IRoGG9Tm1Y3gNKB4zaRLNVRvrZEHCV7oxPyhrXdVSspjDTezqkAzD2MWTtz37zHGZeLx4e4dbXmQ4m/bvC2RIOeOYUuc8gLKlcvmaGwDovw)

This basically calculate the `x*y` in base 62
For a recursive solution at 125 bytes

```python
x,y=input()
r=range;b=map(chr,r(97,123)+r(65,91)+r(48,58))
f=lambda i:(f(i/62)if~-i/62>0else'')+b[i%62-1]
print f(int(x*y)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Fcy9DoIwFEDhnadgMdxbSuwPVNDUFyEMRVttAg2pmMDiqyNs33BytoWu2ofpOwMmUUcTXvbW69FM8HhHGqG5UC4k5hFURRt@oKxpVSMmTg9m7J8m9Vdw4M9KoHe/4sCd2eFjswzzvvUnJQreJVP0YU73MMywkBVzjtvWSsUYESWR@z7ljLHuDw)