# Bijective Function (mapping integer to arbitrarily large integer tuple)

Tags: code-golf, open-ended-function

Find a bijective function which maps integers to arbitrarily large tuples of integers. Given the input \$n\$, output the tuple it matches to.

Edit: The empty tuple is included in the mapping.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want _integers_: negative, 0, and positive?

Comment: This is basically the same as [Map a list of indefinite size to a number!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/78975/39242) and [Pack sequences of non-negative integers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/26562/39242).